# How do I plot a double bar chart to compare patient discharges and admissions for different feed types?

Tags: python, plotly

[image]

Basically, I need a pairs of two bars next to each other. An example of the data that I'm trying to plot is shown:

|  | Patients discharged | Patients admitted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Feed type A | 10 | 29 |
| Feed type B | 68 | 52 |

The graph would show a bar representing patients discharged and patients admitted for each feed type right next to each other. All bar representing patients discharged and patients admitted would be of the same colour respectively.

Comment: I think the graph you are looking for is a grouping of bars, see this in the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/#grouped-bar-chart).